# Overriding Gem Parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, spree

I'm using Spree Commerce `3-0-stable` for an ecommerce app, and I'm trying to override the default `Order` prefix but can't seem to find the appropriate way to do this. The gem sets the prefix like this

`include Spree::Core::NumberGenerator.new(prefix: 'R')`

Here's the whole file https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/app/models/spree/order.rb#L16

And the `NumberGenerator` helper is here:
https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/lib/spree/core/number_generator.rb

What would be the best way to change this prefix? I'm kind of lost given the initialization is done directly on the include.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

from my point of view somebody at spree should be slapped in the face for that code...

never the less, i think you can easily change it. i tried to create a minimal useful example for you

```
class NumberGenerator < Module
  attr_accessor :prefix

  def initialize(options)
    @prefix = options.fetch(:prefix)
  end

  def included(klazz)
    number_generator = self
    klazz.class_eval do
      define_singleton_method(:number_generator) { number_generator }
    end
  end
end

class Order
  include NumberGenerator.new(prefix: 'R')
end

puts Order.number_generator.prefix # => R
Order.number_generator.prefix = 'Q'
puts Order.number_generator.prefix # => Q
```

Answer (score 0):

In you spree.rb just add,

```
Spree::Order.number_generator.prefix = 'Q'
```